# Is it possible to call another view controller's tableview didSelect index path and execute it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

First of all

I have a ViewController, it has Button

That button will be back to specific ViewController through Navigation

```
var viewControllers = self.navigationController!.viewControllers

while !(viewControllers.last is MainViewController) {  
             viewControllers.removeLast()
          }

let destinationViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "destinationViewController") as! destinationViewController

viewControllers.append(destinationViewController)

self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: false)
```

In my destinationViewController has TableView

I need to automatically conduct First row

So I write down these code before setViewControllers above

But get nil

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
destinationViewController.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
```

Here's destinationViewController

```
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
      }
}
    extension DestinationViewController:UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
        //Here is user select can be triggered, but I want to call from another viewController
       }
    }
```

My question is how should I call tableView's row that I want from another viewController ?

Comment: Before initializing the tableView the indexPath will be nil because it's not loaded. After completing loading tableView you can get the first row from tableView. Otherwise not.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed but when/where should I get first index row and call didSelectRowAt? I know what you mean but I don't know where I can call properly ?or fix this situation

Comment: You can get the first index in ViewDidLoad of DestinationViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than 
`destinationViewController.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)`, why not call:

```swift
destinationViewController.
    tableView(destinationViewController.tableView, 
    didSelectRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
```

Comment: I change the code that you provide, but it still get nil.
Do you have idea to solve problem that I encounter?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `But get nil`? that method is `Void` it won't return anything? What are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 0):

simply do one thing, in your destination viewController update your tableView after viewDidAppear.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)
}
```